# How do you convert `props.children` to a JSX element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With React functional components, we can render children like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = (props: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
    return props.children;
}
```

However, when I go to use this I get an error:

```js
...
    return <MyComponent />;
...
```

or

```js
...
    return (
        <MyComponent>
            <div>hello</div>
        </MyComponent>
    );
...
```

leads to

```
'MyComponent' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.
```

One solution is to wrap the functional component's return value in a fragment:

```js
const MyComponent = (props: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
    return <>{props.children}</>; // <= useless fragment is here
}
```

However, then I trigger the `eslint: react/jsx-no-useless-fragment` error.

Is there a way use the children such that I don't have either of these issues?

#### Edit

Here is a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BZATwGFdIakb4BeOABRgcYOgC5ExGADoACiLoB1YDAAWrVcAA2AEyI0AlHF4A+OAG9yca3CIwArlBpxhEUdLSbd+0jb-+AegC4AB5+ABUAZTgkKBwoABo4GggYui1gHhi46DorGyDbJAcnUJNzV3dPbT1uAF8QgJNfOEKw5NSo7PikonQYAIArOgAPAFoUsfs6JC0kOjox7BQAcxBueHmMrNj48jqKKloGOAB5NVj2cFoN40EjUwt86ztHZwFn-xCdYAA3E0+-hsIRYV04GwBQKhwJ+-1Usy0EEasMh0OBAVBHBuPFRQORf1xcAMFAO5CAA)

Is there a way to convert from a ReactNode to a valid JSX component other than by using a fragment?

**Additional Note**: *`eslint-plugin-react` [has an option](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md#allowexpressions) for `allowExpressions` that covers this use case. Essentially it will allow "useless" fragments when the fragment is doing the job of `ReactNode` => JSX element conversion.*

Comment: When using it as `<MyComponent />`, you are providing no children. Instead, you should do `<MyComponent><p>stuff here</p></>` or whatever you need to have as its children.

Comment: Children being present there doesn't change the error. I added a playground link so you can see.

Comment: When I searched for `React.PropsWithChildren`, I found nothing but non-official sites. Have you tried specifying props as `{children: JSX.Element}`? That `PropsWithChildren` could be something other than something renderable.

Comment: You are right; the official documentation for this stuff doesn't really exist. [@types/react provides PropsWithChildren](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L799). I prefer to use the official type definitions from DefinitelyTyped rather than creating my own `{children: ...}` type, but you're right that that does work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "useless" fragment is actually the same as calling

```js
React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, props.children);
```

[`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) is able to use a component type (`React.Fragment`) and children to create a JSX element of that type with those children.

So the solution is to do this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
    return React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, props.children);
}
```

That makes TS and eslint both happy. However, JSX is favored over `createElement`. Enabling the option `{"allowExpressions": true}` for the eslint rule (see question for more details) and using a JSX-style fragment is the best choice here.

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 important points I see here:

1. The revision you provided in your last code block with the children wrapped in a fragment is important in Typescript. Children can be an array of elements which would not be a valid element so it needs to be wrapped in a valid element to cover that case (or checked to ensure it's not an array). (At least in Typescript and React before v16.)
2. The eslint rule you reference that causes the 2nd error is triggered because there's only one item inside the fragment. However, since that's what we want to fit the Typescript definition, that's problematic. I'd recommend silencing that error in this specific case.

One option is adding a disable comment on the line before the return like this:

```js
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-useless-fragment
    return <>{props.children}</>;
```

Comment: I edited the question. For 1. I want to make it renderable by converting from a `ReactNode` to a JSX element. For 2. that is true, but I don't think it's relevant here.

Comment: I've edited my answer. After reviewing the eslint rule, I can see that it was triggered because of a single item inside the fragment instead of no item (or undefined) like I had guessed before. Thus, I can see how my original point 2 about not providing the children wasn't applicable as you said.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known issue with JSX + Typescript.

The answer is that the useless fragment is in fact, not useless in Typescript. I would wrap children in a fragment.

The ESLint plugin author even has a note and solve to the rule by enabling `allowExpressions` in the rule:

https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md#allowexpressions

> When true single expressions in a fragment will be allowed. This is useful in places like Typescript where string does not satisfy the expected return type of JSX.Element. A common workaround is to wrap the variable holding a string in a fragment and expression.

Comment: It's funny, I added this to my question as an edit less than a minute before you posted this answer XD. For my case, this solves the problem. However, I'm still looking for a way to convert from a `ReactNode` to a valid JSX element without using a fragment. Essentially I want to know how to do this without using JSX. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got mine to work using MUI animations, I wanted to implement DRY code for the  component which adds some baked in css transform animation.

```
//Reusable component I want to pass a childComponent to.

const AnimateComponent = (props: {isComponent: boolean, childComponent: JSX.Element}) => {
  const { isComponent, childComponent } = props;
  return (
    <Grow
      in={isComponent}
      {... isComponent ? { timeout: 1000 } : {}}
    >
      {childComponent}
    </Grow>
  )
}

//App.tsx
<AnimateComponent
  isComponent={focus === ContentView.About } 
  childComponent={<AboutComponent/>}  
/>
```